# How to get list of coordinates for street paths with the Android Google Maps API's?

Tags: android, google-maps, path, coordinates

Is there any way to get information about the streets in a given radius around a specific point in the map. Specifically, for each street overlapped by my half mile radius area, I would like to get a list of coordinates that mark the path of each street.


Does the Android Google Maps API offer this? If not, is there another service other than Google Maps that does this?